# Remove 'Theme Options' Option Tree Wordpress

Tags: plugin-option-tree

I use the Options Tree. Just to use a Meta Box only. And I do not use his Theme Options.

In the picture below, how to throw Theme Options menu? 
Is it possible?

[image: Option Tree Theme Options]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be removed using `remove_submenu_page` function. Put following codes in your `functions.php`

```
function remove_ot_menu () {
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'ot-theme-options' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_ot_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Option Tree Files
 * Including Files and setting up Option Tree
 *
 * @Since 1.0.0
 * Version 1.0.0
 */
if(class_exists('OT_Loader' )): 
            //Filter for option tree settings
    add_filter( 'ot_show_pages', '__return_false' );
    add_filter( 'ot_show_new_layout', '__return_false' );
    add_filter( 'ot_post_formats', '__return_true');
    add_filter( 'ot_use_theme_options', '__return_false' ); //This filter removes theme options page.
endif;
```

The code above is helpful to remove custom Theme options page from Option Tree, make sure you add this in functions.php